# Symfony 4 - Edit entity

Tags: php, symfony

I develop a project under symfony 4, I have a User entity composed of several attributes. I created a login / registration. By constraint, I set up a captcha for the inscription. For that I then put a mandatory validation in my User entity to validate or not the captcha during registration.

Here is my problem:

I have developed a user profile editing system so that a user can edit their personal information. For this, I have no need for captcha validation. However, this captcha is linked to my Entity User and it must be valid, so I have to set up a captcha when editing a user profile or I have an error telling me that the captcha is not valid.

I would like to be able to avoid the integration of the captcha for the edition of a user profile. Do you have one or more solutions for me?

thank you so much

Comment: Hi Stackoverflow is for questions in english language only.
Bonjour, seules les questions en anglais sont acceptées sur Stackoverflow.

Comment: Why not remove the captcha from the form, or add it only in case of registration?

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: That's what I do but my captcha has a validation on my Entity User so when editing my profile it looks if everything is valid in relation to my User entity and as I have no captcha on the form of I have an error because it is not valid

Comment: Hi, did you read about validation groups in the symfony docs?

Comment: I will watch thanks